# Posting and reading Json through different controllers

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send an object from Controller A to Controller B. Which parameter must receive B to process the data that I send from A with a POST.

The POST on A is made inside a controller using HttpClient not via jquery

Comment: Is your data a JSON formatted string? If so then that JSON string is the body of your HTTP request, and your HTTP header would be application/json.

Comment: If not then some code to show the two action methods of controller A and B with your initial attempt stubbed out might clarify what your asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that you have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

that your Controller B's action takes as parameter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

you could use the HttpClient to send the model as JSON:

```
var model = new MyViewModel
{
    Id = 123,
    Foo = "bar",
};
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

Comment: what about if my Controller A is hosted on a different projects and they don't share the same ViewModel(but you can send the json), how can I read the Json from the parameter?

Comment: In all cases you need to send the proper JSON. So either you move this `MyViewModel` class to a third common project being shared between both your controllers or you duplicate it on the client project. I am not sure what you mean by your question: `how can I read the Json from the parameter?` What parameter are you talking about? What's it's structure? Is it the same as what Controller B expects? How is it sent to Controller A?

Comment: Can I read the json from the parameter like a string and deserialized it? if Yes, which is the signature of the method?

Comment: I tried this approach but with not success, the model received in the post comes with null values inside, even the response that I get with Json comes null, but when I posted all the models they had the correct values